# Passing ID of selected DIV to next PHP page without form or URL variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've got some variables that I have in javascript that are:

```
window.location.href = 'chosendivs.php?Selected=' + qs;
```

where qs is an array of different div ID's that passes to the next page in the URL as follows:

```
chosendivs.php?Selected=d41%2Cd42
```

I don't like the idea of passing these divs through the URL, is there another way other than using a form to post them?

Answer (score 1):

You can send an [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) request with `POST` like

```
qs= [];
qs[0] = 'id1';
qs[1] = 'id2';
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {qs:qs},
   url: "http://localhost/{web_server}/chosendivs.php",
});
```

and if you do a `var_dump($_POST)` at `chosendivs.php` the array will be displayed as JSON format. You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to manipulate data at PHP end

Comment: Thanks for this but i'm getting `$.serialize is not a function` ?